# wsimport bind xsd:int to Integer instead of int

Tags: java, wsimport

Ok. The title really says it all.

I have a extremely large SOAP server I'm calling in a java application. To make my life easier I've been using wsimport to generate the source and jar for the service. I just ran into a problem. All the xsd:int types in the wsdl are being parsed as int types in the java code when I need them as Integer types. Reason for this is some of the int's i need to set as null, but since int types can't be null I can't do that.

I am currently going through and hand changing the fields, but I want to know if there is a easier way to do it through a agrument to the wsimport command

Here is my current wsimport command. Thanks

```
wsimport.exe -d E:\ServiceWSBuild -p com.example.wsdl -s E:\Service\src -verbose http://wsdl.example.com/?wsdl
```

Here is also a example of one of the custom types that does this:

```
 <xsd:complexType name="SubPackageSell">
  <xsd:complexContent>
   <xsd:extension base="tns:APIObject">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="sp" type="tns:SubPackage"/>
   <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:int"/>
   <xsd:element name="days" type="xsd:int"/>
   <xsd:element name="date" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="combine" type="xsd:boolean"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:extension>
  </xsd:complexContent>
 </xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: Attributes with `use="required"` will be a primitive `int`, otherwise they will be `java.lang.Integer`

Comment: I added a example of one of the complex types. As you see there is no required listed in the atributes.

Comment: Sorry, assumed you were using attributes not elements. See my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For elements, specify `minOccurs="0"` and wsimport should generate a `java.lang.Integer` instead of a primitive `int`. The default values for `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` is 1, which is why you are getting primitive `int`s. For example:

```
<xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/>
```

Comment: so basically it's all up to the wsdl.. Which means you cant control the way your client code(e.g.) will be generated.